# Troubleshooting SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Patient activity table that records every activity of the patient right from the time the patient got admitted to the hospital till the patient got discharged. Here is the table command

```
Create table activity
(  activityid int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   calendarid int
   admissionID int,
   activitydescription varchar(100),
   admitTime datetime,
   dischargetime datetime,
   foreign key (admissionID) references admission(admissionID)
)
```

The data looks like this:

```
     activityID   calendarid   admissionID    activitydescription    admitTime            dischargeTime 
       1             100           10             Patient Admitted     1/1/2013 10:15      -1
       2             100           10             Activity 1            -1                 -1
       3             100           10             Activity 2            -1                 -1
       4             100           10             Patient Discharged    -1                 1/4/2013 13:15
```

For every calendarID defined, the set of admissionid repeats. For a given calendarid, the admissionsid(s) are unique. For my analysis, I want to write a query to display admissionid, calendarid, admitTime and dischargetime.

```
 select admissionId, calendarid, admitTime=
         (select distinct admitTime 
         from activity a1 
         where a1.admisionID=a.admissionID and a1.calendarID=a.calendarid),
     dischargeTime=
         (select distinct dischargeTime 
         from activity a1 
         where a1.admisionID=a.admissionID and a1.calendarID=a.calendarid)
 from activity a
 where calendarid=100
```

When I individually assign numbers, it works, otherwise it comes up with this message:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When used in this manner, a subquery must return only one record (as clearly stated in the error message).  It looks like if you add `top 1` with an `Order By` on `activityID` that it will do what you want.  Based on test data, it looks like you can avoid the subquery altogether and add `and activitID = 1` to your `Where` clause, though.

Comment: Where admitTime != -1 and dischargetime != -1 should help...

Comment: Can you create an sql fiddle for this ? or maybe give queries to create all the necessary tables and some sample rows ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this !

```
select admissionId, calendarid, admitTime=
         (select top(1) admitTime 
         from activity a1 
         where a1.admisionID=a.admissionID and a1.calendarID=a.calendarid),
     dischargeTime=
         (select top(1) dischargeTime 
         from activity a1 
         where a1.admisionID=a.admissionID and a1.calendarID=a.calendarid)
 from activity a
 where calendarid=100
```

Comment: Without an `Order By` clause you have no guarantee that you will not pull -1 as the `admitTime` or the `dischargeTime`.

Comment: Then I'd like to see SQL fiddle for that ! This might have answered what op asked ! Blindly giving a -1 is unfair !! I read in one of the blogs that so lacks maturity ! May be due to this reason 

Comment: I gave the -1, after I explained the reasoning, although I did not explicitly state that I was the one that gave the mark down.  Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb279/2/0).  Also [ordering reading](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/24/sql-server-order-of-result-set-of-select-statement-on-clustered-indexed-table-when-order-by-is-not-used/)

Comment: None of the answers below have a order by clause why not down vote them ! And can you pls tell ideally what output it should be !!?Sayōnara

Comment: Top(1) definitely helped, but I had to put an order by clause in order to pull the right data. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` does not return 1 row, it returns all **distinct** rows given the columns you provided in the select clause.  That's why you're getting more than one value back from the subquery.

What are you looking for out of the sub-query?  If you use `TOP 1` instead of `DISTINCT`, that should work, but it might not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message tells a lot. Obviously, one (or both) of your projection subqueries in the (the `SELECT DISTINCT` queries) return more than one value. Thus, the columns `admitTime`, resp. `dischargeTime` cannot be compared to the result.

One possibility would be to limit your subqueries to 1 row. However, this error might also indicate a structural problem in your DB design.

Try:

```
select top 1 admitTime 
from activity a1 
where a1.admisionID=a.admissionID and a1.calendarID=a.calendarid
```

or

```
select admitTime 
from activity a1 
where a1.admisionID=a.admissionID and a1.calendarID=a.calendarid
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want, with a bit less of a performance hit than subqueries:

```
select  a1.admissionId
        ,a1.calendarid
        ,a2.admitTime
        ,a3.dischargeTime
from    activity a1
left join activity a2
    on  a1.calendarid = a2.calendarid
    and a2.admitTime <> -1
left join activity a3
    on  a1.calendarid = a3.calendarid
    and a3.dischargeTime <> -1
where a1.calendarid=100
```